# Sorting uniquely from a row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, scripting

Can you please give me suggestion how do I can uniquely sort from a line or row? I have information like this:

```
Special   c1,c2,c5,c7,c1,c2   
Special2  C6
```

(that's a TAB character in between `Special` and `c1...`).

I want the output like this:

```
Special   c1,c2,c5,c7  
Special2  C6
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Considering that there is no reliable delimiter in your example, I doubt you'd be able to sort them yourself to your satisfaction.  Programming involves defining the rules to apply.

Comment: yes they are tab delimited.

Comment: And yet in your example, they are comma-delimited.

Comment: I mean Special and the numbers are in two columns actually and they are tab delimited. sorry for my misinformation.

Comment: Do you merely require for duplicates to be removed (which could be done e.g. with a fairly simple `sed` script) or do you genuinely require the second field to be sorted?

Comment: @tripleee yes, I need the answer

Comment: "Yes, I didn't read the question properly" or "no, I need both"?

Answer (score 9):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739/874188),

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -laF'\t' -ne '
    $F[1] = join(",", uniq(sort(split(",", $F[1])))); print join("\t", @F)'
```

This depends on an external package [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/).  If you don't want to install an external dependency, reimplementing the `uniq` function is [just a few more lines of Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657/874188).  (Though I seem to have it installed as part of the base system on macOS.)

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -F'\t|,' -lane 'my %h; print shift @F, "\t", join ",", sort grep !$h{$_}++, @F' dataf
```

---

### Explanation

- `-F'\t|,'` => will split each record fields into the array `@F` on `TAB` or `comma` characters.
- `-l` will set the `RS` to `newline` and `ORS` to `newline` as well.
- `-a` will autosplit each record into words based on the `FS` chosen by `-F`.
- `-n` will setup an implicit record read in loop on the input `AND` will print things only when asked to.
- `-e` is the `Perl` code to be executed upon each record of the input based on `RS` choen by `-l` above.
- The first element will be given by `shift` and the remaining elements will be `uniquified` via storing them as keys of a hash, `%h`, which shall be regenerated every time a record read in. The unique elements are then sorted and joined with a comma and printed.

Answer (score 5):

***gawk***(GNU awk) approach:

```
 awk '{if($2~/.*,.*/){l=split($2,a,","); asort(a); $2=a[1]; b[a[1]]++;
      for(i=2;i<=l;i++) $2=(!b[a[i]]++)? $2","a[i] : $2 }}1' file
```

The output:

```
Special c1,c2,c5,c7
Special2  C6
```

---

`if($2~/.*,.*/)` - if we have multiple comma-separated items in the second field

`l=split($2,a,",")` - dividing string into pieces separated by `,`.
 
`l` is assigned with number of pieces

`asort(a)` - sorts an array of substrings

`$2=(!b[a[i]]++)? $2","a[i] : $2` - considering unique items

Comment: `asort` is a GNU Awk extension, isn't it?

Comment: @tripleee, and I added `g` -> `gawk`

Answer (score 5):

Tested with OpenBSD `awk`, GNU `awk` and `mawk`:

```
awk -F ',| +' '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) { print $1, $i } }' data.in |
sort -u |
awk '{ f[$1] = (f[$1] ? f[$1] "," : "") $2 } END { for (k in f) { print k, f[k] } }'
```

The first `awk` expands the given data into

```
Special c1
Special c2
Special c5
Special c7
Special c1
Special c2
Special2 C6
```

It uses both commas and multiple spaces as field delimiter and, for each record (line) of input, it prints the first field followed by each of the other fields in turn on separate lines. This assumes that there are no other spaces or commas on the lines other than where they will be properly interpreted as delimiters.

The `sort` in the middle sorts it into

```
Special2 C6
Special c1
Special c2
Special c5
Special c7
```

It does a sort using the full line as the sorting key and discards any duplicate line.

The last `awk` recombines the data into

```
Special c1,c2,c5,c7
Special2 C6
```

It does this by using the first field as a key into an associative array and stores the comma-separated concatenation of the corresponding data in the second field as the value. At the end, all collected data is printed.

Answer (score 2):

Another way in one line:

```
while read line; do echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ';  echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}' | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/.$//g'; echo; done < file_to_sort
```

It takes the first column of every line (`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ';`) and sort the second column values separated by ',' after converting it in a single column in order to apply `sort` and then converting it back to a single row with the original formatting (`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ','`).

Doing line splitting as suggested by @tripleee:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read first second; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$first" "$(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$second" | sort | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/.$//g';)"; done < file_to_sort
```

Comment: You could do the line splitting in the shell with `while IFS=$'\t' read first second; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$first" "$(tr ',' '\n' <<<"$second" | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//')"; done` (this obviously uses some Bash constructs, so `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bin/sh`).